# WSO2 Data Services Transaction Management

Tags: wso2-data-services-server

I am trying to develop a service using WSO2 Data Service and using Boxcarring sessions for transaction management.

I observed that while executing a Update statement in boxcarring, row is not locked. I can access same row using DB tool and even change its value.

As In our case many applications will be accessing the same row and here it is not locked. Can someone suggest me on how to turn this into proper transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through the docs and source code It seems like, data service add request in a list and when that session is ended or committed,  request are executed or rejected. So it does not lock a row when you start a boxcarring session.  Please check the highlighted line from doc page and source code links.

https://github.com/wso2/platform/blob/master/components/data-services/org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/dataservices/core/boxcarring/RequestBox.java

https://github.com/wso2/platform/blob/master/components/data-services/org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/dataservices/core/DSSessionManager.java

Please also check the Point # 5 on Boxcarring+Sample

"5. Note that the salary is not incremented. The reason is that the request made earlier in boxcarring mode is not executed immediately. It is executed when the boxcarring session ends."

Reference docs.wso2.com/display/DSS321/Boxcarring+Sample

Answer (score 1):

Boxcarring allows multiple data service calls to be sent to server side and be executed at once. It can be used to make sure related data service calls gets executed completely or not at all(in this way it is similar to database transactions). IMO it is not DSS's job to lock any database values as it should be working on the service level.